# How to restrict the NTFS Linux partition on Windows in Dual Boot systems

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, boot-partition

I have partitioned my 1 TB hard disk to 500GB for windows and 400GB for Linux.
I however don't want Windows to be using the 400 GB partition of Linux when I boot Windows because windows is creating some metadata which it is storing in the 400GB partition. How do I go about this? I don't want it to show up at all or only give a read access on Windows?

Comment: If the question is about Windows and NTFS, this should be asked on [su].

Comment: And an easy solution would be not formating it in NTFS if you don't need/want Windows to use it. A proper option would be EXT4 instead.

Comment: Windows can't read Linux partition unless you install a third party package which will actually brick 64-bit Linux ext4 partitions these days.

Comment: I agree that EXT4 is an option but I have few files on my Linux Partition and I'm not super willing to format it at this point. I need a solution more like permissions wise. I kinda messed with this and ended up giving up my Full Control permissions as System and Admin as well. So, I have no way to change the permissions and I am super stuck right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply unmount the Linux NTFS partitions in Windows. Here is how:

1. Press Win + R and run this command - `diskmgmt.msc`.
2. Right click the partition you wanna unmount, then remove the drive letter from it.

Done! It'll do the thing.

Comment: I thought about this but I would have to unmount it every single time. I need a solution more like permissions wise. I kinda messed with this and ended up giving up my Full Control permissions as System and Admin as well. So, I have no way to change the permissions.